# Python 3.5 uninstall Windows 7

Tags: python, uninstallation

I have Windows 7 64 Bit. By mistake I installed Python 3.5 32 bit. I want to uninstall it (for installing 64 Bit version) but dont know how to do it (It does not get uninstalled from Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program). I googled it and found some links but could not understand / was not able to do it.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Find the uninstall shortcut link in the python folder on win start menu Or in Python's install folder, then uninstall it.

If you can not find either, I think you should just delete the python install folder, then everything should be ok after you install the python x64.

Because for many program just the files in install folder are x86/x64 dependent, other files in the user folder is not.

P.S.
Installation folder maybe locate in `c:\\programs/python35/`or in something like `c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`

Comment: I think it's ok just to delete folder too. Installation path should be something like `c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\`

Comment: @germn Thanks for notice the install folder in ...appdata...